# ActionBar: Share button not working

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, share-intent

I am trying to develop an `ActionBar` which contains a share button, but if the user clicks on the share nothing happens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    ...
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the app compat's action provider as:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Comment: I'm having same problem that the share item is not clickable, although I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` any ideas ?